# How to alignment each JPanel to left or to right into main JPanel

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jpanel, layout-manager

I wanna my app look like this:

[image: View Image]

I have to try use

```
jpanel.setAlignmentX(JPanel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
jpanel.setAlignmentX(JPanel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
```

But it's working for first jpanel when I add it into main_JPanel. [Show correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVgX2.jpg)
But when I add the JPanel2, JPanel3,... then main_Panel show not correctly, it show this:

[image: Error show jpanel]

This my function create each JPanel

```
public JPanel makeJpanel(String Mess, String username) {
        int height = 40;
        int width = 200;
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        String rs = splitMess(Mess);
        Mess = rs.substring(2).trim();

        Style style = textPane.addStyle("I'm a Style", null);

        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Arial");
        StyleConstants.setBold(style, true);
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 20);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, new Color(19, 51, 55));
        try {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), Mess.trim(), style);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        }
        height = (int) Math.round(textPane.getPreferredSize().getHeight());
        width = (int) Math.round(textPane.getPreferredSize().getWidth());

        //creat avatar
        JLabel ava = null;
        if (username.equals(this.userName)) {
            ava = new JLabel(label_myAvaProfile1.getIcon());
        } else {
            ava = new JLabel(label_avaYourFriends1.getIcon());
        }
        JLabel borderAva = new JLabel(border_label_avaYourFriends.getIcon());
        if (height < 40) {
            ava.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
            borderAva.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        } else {
            ava.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, height));
            borderAva.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, height));
        }
        JLayeredPane lpAva = new JLayeredPane();
        lpAva.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(lpAva));
        lpAva.add(borderAva);
        lpAva.add(ava);

        JPanel panelChat = new JPanel();
        panelChat.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelChat, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        panelChat.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelChat.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width + 40, height));
        panelChat.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width + 40, height));
        panelChat.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width + 40, height));
        if (username.equals(this.userName)) {
            panelChat.add(textPane);
            panelChat.add(lpAva);
            //NOTICE THIS
            panelChat.setAlignmentX(JPanel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        } else if (username.equals(currentFriendUserName)) {
            panelChat.add(lpAva);
            panelChat.add(textPane);
            //NOTICE THIS
            panelChat.setAlignmentX(JPanel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        }

        resetPanelListFriends(panelChat);
        return panelChat;
    }
```

This function I call when i add new Jpanel

```
public void renderPanelChatLog()
{
    JPanel panelChat = new JPanel();
        panelChat = makeJPanel(mess, username);
        if (panelChat != null) {
            panel_ChatLog.add(panelChat);
            panel_ChatLog.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
        }
        resetPanelListFriends(panel_ChatLog);
}
```

Sorry My English, I'm just new guy... Plzz help me!

Comment: In the future post a [mre] that demonstrates your problem. We are not interested in your application, only code that demonstrates the problem. The details of how you create the child panel is irrelevant to your problem. Your question is about alignment, not the components added to the panel. My answer is in the form of an "MRE".

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class BoxLayoutAligned
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JLabel left = new JLabel( "Left Aligned" );
        Box leftBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        leftBox.add( left );
        leftBox.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );

        JLabel right = new JLabel( "Right Aligned" );
        Box rightBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        rightBox.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );
        rightBox.add( right );

        Box vertical = Box.createVerticalBox();
        vertical.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10) );
        vertical.add( leftBox );
        vertical.add( rightBox );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoxLayout Aligned");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(vertical);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

By adding "glue" you allow the other components added to the Box to be aligned to the left or right.